# Parallel execution of robot tests in Sauce Labs

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, automated-tests, robotframework, saucelabs

I am using Eclipse+Maven based Robot Framework with Java implementation of SeleniumLibrary.

I could execute tests in sauce labs but it executes only on one VM. Has anyone achieved parallel execution of robot tests in Sauce Labs say in multiple VMs? Or can anyone guide to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with: "... executes on one VM." Given that SauceLabs is often implemented as a Selenium Grid Server replacement, you'd expect a single URL, but behind it will be several browser instances - depending upon your contract.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using to run on multiple concurrent VM's on saucelabs.  I have a 1-click batch file that uses `start pybot` to invoke parallel execution.  Example:

```
ECHO starting parallel run on saucelabs.com
cd c:\base\dir\script

ECHO Win7/Chrome40:
start pybot -v REMOTE_URL:http://user:key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub -T    -d results/Win7Chrome40  -v DESIRED_CAPABILITIES:"name:Win7 + Chrome40, platform:Windows 7, browserName:chrome, version:40"  tests/test.robot

ECHO Win8/IE11
start pybot -v REMOTE_URL:http://user:key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub -T    -d results/Win8IE11      -v DESIRED_CAPABILITIES:"name:Win8 + IE11, platform:Windows 8.1, browserName:internet explorer, version:11"  tests/test.robot
```

`-T` tells pybot to not overwrite result logs but create a timestamped log for each run

`-d` specifies where the results will go

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

A parallel executor for Robot Framework tests. With Pabot you can split one execution into multiple and save test execution time.
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes